# Como impedir refresh após submit na mesma página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, php-7

Tenho um formulário básico HTML que envia os dados através do método POST para a mesma página, ou seja, faço o submit para a própria página.
Como nessa página tem ações em Javascript, após esse submit a página reseta, acontecendo um refresh, resetando checkbox por exemplo e eu gostaria que as escolhas que a pessoa realizou ficassem mantidas.
É possível impedir esse refresh após clicar no botão submit do formulário?

Comment: a página vai sempre fazer refresh se o action do seu form está pra essa página. crie uma funcão JS para tratar do submit dos dados do form.

Answer (score 1):

O caminho lógico e mais fácil seria efetuar essa requisição post com Ajax! O que manteria a seleção dos campos conforme o usuário optou.

Mas se está submetendo para a mesma página, você pode acessar os valores através da variável **$_POST** do php.

exemplo teste.php:

```
 <form action='teste.php' method='POST'>
   <input type='text' name='nome' value="<?= (!empty($_POST['nome']))? 
   $_POST['nome'] : '' ?>">
 </form>
```

Ou seja se houver valor na variavel **NOME** enviada por POST adicione no atributo value do campo de texto chamado **nome** caso contrário adicione vazio.

Conteúdo adicional : [PHP POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Compreendi. Vou trabalhar em cima disso e verei se deu certo. Obrigado pela dica e atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Não, não é possível impedir esse refresh fazendo o submit do form para a própria página.

Você deve efectuar essa requisiçãi via ajax - guardava na Base de Dados mas não retornava nada para o html.

Assim conseguiria inserir os dados e manter os dados.

**Alternativa**

Se o seu objectivo é manter os dados, você pode verificar se $_POST contém dados (após fazer o submit irá conter). Se conter, pode escrever esses dados nos values dos insputs do form. Desta forma, faria o refresh no entanto iria preencher os campos com os valores inseridos antes do submit e que foram enviados.

Comment: Entendi. Já que não pode, trabalharei em cima dessas dicas para chegar no que pretendo. Agradeço sua atenção, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: - Impedir o submit.
Segundo: - Enviar o submit via ajax.
Terceiro: Dependendo da resposta do ajax, sair, mostrar msg, etc.

EXEMPLO:
Para impedir o submit:
Usando jQuery:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("#formulario_tal").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // impedir o evento submit

    // aqui entra o codigo ajax. pesquisar no google "jquery ajax" para mais detalhes

  });
});
```

Um exemplo prático: 
https://codepen.io/fixonweb/pen/jOOPwPL

Answer (score -3):

Basta inserir no codigo do submit o return false.

ex:

`<input type="submit" onclick="calcular();return false" />`